# how to export bind and keyframe bone poses from blender to use in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, animation, blender

****EDIT2:**

Please avoid pointing out efficiency / optimization issues; this is not final code at all. This is just me trying the basics out :). Once I get everything down I'll go about cleaning up and optimizing.

**EDIT:** I decided to reformulate the question in much simpler terms to see if someone can give me a hand with this.

Basically, I'm exporting meshes, skeletons and actions from blender into an engine of sorts that I'm working on. But I'm getting the animations wrong. I can tell the basic motion paths are being followed but there's always an axis of translation or rotation which is wrong. I think the problem is most likely not in my engine code (OpenGL-based) but rather in either my misunderstanding of some part of the theory behind skeletal animation / skinning or the way I am exporting the appropriate joint matrices from blender in my exporter script.

I'll explain the theory, the engine animation system and my blender export script, hoping someone might catch the error in either or all of these.

**The theory: (I'm using column-major ordering since that's what I use in the engine cause it's OpenGL-based)**

- Assume I have a mesh made up of a single vertex v, along with a
  transformation matrix M which takes the vertex v from the mesh's
  local space to world space. That is, if I was to render the mesh
  without a skeleton, the final position would be gl_Position =
  ProjectionMatrix * M * v.
- Now assume I have a skeleton with a single joint j in bind / rest
  pose. j is actually another matrix. A transform from j's local space
  to its parent space which I'll denote Bj. if j was part of a joint
  hierarchy in the skeleton, Bj would take from j space to j-1 space
  (that is to its parent space). However, in this example j is the only
  joint, so Bj takes from j space to world space, like M does for v.
- Now further assume I have a a set of frames, each with a second
  transform Cj, which works the same as Bj only that for a different,
  arbitrary spatial configuration of join j. Cj still takes vertices
  from j space to world space but j is rotated and/or translated and/or
  scaled.

Given the above, in order to skin vertex v at keyframe n. I need to:

1. take v from world space to joint j space
2. modify j (while v stays fixed in j space and is thus taken along in
   the transformation)
3. take v back from the modified j space to world space

So the mathematical implementation of the above would be:
**v' = Cj * Bj^-1 * v**. 
Actually, I have one doubt here.. I said the mesh to which v belongs has a transform M which takes from model space to world space. And I've also read in a couple textbooks that it needs to be transformed from **model** space to joint space. But I also said in 1 that v needs to be transformed from world to joint space. So basically I'm not sure if I need to do **v' = Cj * Bj^-1 * v** or **v' = Cj * Bj^-1 * M * v**. Right now my implementation multiples v' by M and not v. But I've tried changing this and it just screws things up in a different way cause there's something else wrong.

- Finally, If we wanted to skin a vertex to a joint j1 which in turn is a child of a joint j0, Bj1 would be Bj0 * Bj1 and Cj1 would be Cj0 * Cj1. But Since skinning is defined as **v' = Cj * Bj^-1 * v** , Bj1^-1 would be the reverse concatenation of the inverses making up the original product. That is, **v' = Cj0 * Cj1 * Bj1^-1 * Bj0^-1 * v**

**Now on to the implementation (Blender side):**

Assume the following mesh made up of 1 cube, whose vertices are bound to a single joint in a single-joint skeleton:

[image]

Assume also there's a 60-frame, 3-keyframe animation at 60 fps. The animation essentially is:

- keyframe 0: the joint is in bind / rest pose (the way you see it in the image).
- keyframe 30: the joint translates up (+z in blender) some amount and at the same time rotates pi/4 rad clockwise.
- keyframe 59: the joint goes back to the same configuration it was in keyframe 0.

My first source of confusion on the blender side is its coordinate system (as opposed to OpenGL's default) and the different matrices accessible through the python api.

Right now, this is what my export script does about translating **blender's coordinate system to OpenGL's standard system:**

```
    # World transform: Blender -> OpenGL
    worldTransform = Matrix().Identity(4)
    worldTransform *= Matrix.Scale(-1, 4, (0,0,1))
    worldTransform *= Matrix.Rotation(radians(90), 4, "X")

    # Mesh (local) transform matrix
    file.write('Mesh Transform:\n')
    localTransform = mesh.matrix_local.copy()
    localTransform = worldTransform * localTransform
    for col in localTransform.col:
        file.write('{:9f} {:9f} {:9f} {:9f}\n'.format(col[0], col[1], col[2], col[3]))
    file.write('\n')
```

So if you will, my "world" matrix is basically the act of changing blenders coordinate system to the default GL one with +y up, +x right and -z into the viewing volume. Then I also premultiply (in the sense that it's done by the time we reach the engine, not in the sense of post or pre in terms of matrix multiplication order) the mesh matrix M so that I don't need to multiply it again once per draw call in the engine.

**About the possible matrices to extract from Blender joints (bones in Blender parlance), I'm doing the following:**

- **For joint bind poses:**

  ```
  def DFSJointTraversal(file, skeleton, jointList):

  for joint in jointList:
      bindPoseJoint = skeleton.data.bones[joint.name]
      bindPoseTransform = bindPoseJoint.matrix_local.inverted()

      file.write('Joint ' + joint.name + ' Transform {\n')
      translationV = bindPoseTransform.to_translation()
      rotationQ = bindPoseTransform.to_3x3().to_quaternion()
      scaleV = bindPoseTransform.to_scale()
      file.write('T {:9f} {:9f} {:9f}\n'.format(translationV[0], translationV[1], translationV[2]))
      file.write('Q {:9f} {:9f} {:9f} {:9f}\n'.format(rotationQ[1], rotationQ[2], rotationQ[3], rotationQ[0]))
      file.write('S {:9f} {:9f} {:9f}\n'.format(scaleV[0], scaleV[1], scaleV[2]))

      DFSJointTraversal(file, skeleton, joint.children)
      file.write('}\n')
  ```

Note that I'm actually grabbing the inverse of what I think is the bind pose transform Bj. This is so I don't need to invert it in the engine. Also note I went for matrix_local, assuming this is Bj. The other option is plain "matrix", which as far as I can tell is the same only that not homogeneous.

- **For joint current / keyframe poses:**

  ```
  for kfIndex in keyframes:
      bpy.context.scene.frame_set(kfIndex)
      file.write('keyframe: {:d}\n'.format(int(kfIndex)))
      for i in range(0, len(skeleton.data.bones)):
          file.write('joint: {:d}\n'.format(i))

          currentPoseJoint = skeleton.pose.bones[i]
          currentPoseTransform = currentPoseJoint.matrix

          translationV = currentPoseTransform.to_translation()
          rotationQ = currentPoseTransform.to_3x3().to_quaternion()
          scaleV = currentPoseTransform.to_scale()
          file.write('T {:9f} {:9f} {:9f}\n'.format(translationV[0], translationV[1], translationV[2]))
          file.write('Q {:9f} {:9f} {:9f} {:9f}\n'.format(rotationQ[1], rotationQ[2], rotationQ[3], rotationQ[0]))
          file.write('S {:9f} {:9f} {:9f}\n'.format(scaleV[0], scaleV[1], scaleV[2]))

          file.write('\n')
  ```

Note that here I go for skeleton.pose.bones instead of data.bones and that I have a choice of 3 matrices: matrix, matrix_basis and matrix_channel. From the descriptions in the python API docs I'm not super clear which one I should choose, though I think it's the plain matrix. Also note I do not invert the matrix in this case.

**The implementation (Engine / OpenGL side):**

**My animation subsystem** does the following on each update (I'm omitting parts of the update loop where it's figured out which objects need update and time is hardcoded here for simplicity):

```
static double time = 0;
            time =  fmod((time + elapsedTime),1.);
            uint16_t LERPKeyframeNumber = 60 * time;
            uint16_t lkeyframeNumber = 0;
            uint16_t lkeyframeIndex = 0;
            uint16_t rkeyframeNumber = 0;
            uint16_t rkeyframeIndex = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < aClip.keyframesCount; i++) {
                uint16_t keyframeNumber = aClip.keyframes[i].number;
                if (keyframeNumber <= LERPKeyframeNumber) {
                    lkeyframeIndex = i;
                    lkeyframeNumber = keyframeNumber;
                }
                else {
                    rkeyframeIndex = i;
                    rkeyframeNumber = keyframeNumber;
                    break;
                }
            }

            double lTime = lkeyframeNumber / 60.;
            double rTime = rkeyframeNumber / 60.;
            double blendFactor = (time - lTime) / (rTime - lTime);

            GLKMatrix4 bindPosePalette[aSkeleton.jointsCount];
            GLKMatrix4 currentPosePalette[aSkeleton.jointsCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < aSkeleton.jointsCount; i++) {
                F3DETQSType& lPose = aClip.keyframes[lkeyframeIndex].skeletonPose.joints[i];
                F3DETQSType& rPose = aClip.keyframes[rkeyframeIndex].skeletonPose.joints[i];

                GLKVector3 LERPTranslation = GLKVector3Lerp(lPose.t, rPose.t, blendFactor);
                GLKQuaternion SLERPRotation = GLKQuaternionSlerp(lPose.q, rPose.q, blendFactor);
                GLKVector3 LERPScaling = GLKVector3Lerp(lPose.s, rPose.s, blendFactor);

                GLKMatrix4 currentTransform = GLKMatrix4MakeWithQuaternion(SLERPRotation);
                currentTransform =  GLKMatrix4TranslateWithVector3(currentTransform, LERPTranslation);
                currentTransform =  GLKMatrix4ScaleWithVector3(currentTransform, LERPScaling);

                GLKMatrix4 inverseBindTransform = GLKMatrix4MakeWithQuaternion(aSkeleton.joints[i].inverseBindTransform.q);
                inverseBindTransform =  GLKMatrix4TranslateWithVector3(inverseBindTransform, aSkeleton.joints[i].inverseBindTransform.t);
                inverseBindTransform =  GLKMatrix4ScaleWithVector3(inverseBindTransform, aSkeleton.joints[i].inverseBindTransform.s);

                if (aSkeleton.joints[i].parentIndex == -1) {
                    bindPosePalette[i] = inverseBindTransform;
                    currentPosePalette[i] = currentTransform;
                }

                else {
                    bindPosePalette[i] = GLKMatrix4Multiply(inverseBindTransform, bindPosePalette[aSkeleton.joints[i].parentIndex]);
                    currentPosePalette[i] = GLKMatrix4Multiply(currentPosePalette[aSkeleton.joints[i].parentIndex], currentTransform);
                }

                aSkeleton.skinningPalette[i] = GLKMatrix4Multiply(currentPosePalette[i], bindPosePalette[i]);
            }
```

**Finally, this is my vertex shader:**

```
#version 100

uniform mat4 modelMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 skinningPalette[6];
uniform lowp float skinningEnabled;


attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;
attribute vec2 tCoordinates;
attribute vec4 jointsWeights;
attribute vec4 jointsIndices;

varying highp vec2 tCoordinatesVarying;
varying highp float lIntensity;

void main()
{
    tCoordinatesVarying = tCoordinates;

    vec4 skinnedVertexPosition = vec4(0.);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        skinnedVertexPosition += jointsWeights[i] * skinningPalette[int(jointsIndices[i])] * position;
    }

    vec4 skinnedNormal = vec4(0.);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        skinnedNormal += jointsWeights[i] * skinningPalette[int(jointsIndices[i])] * vec4(normal, 0.);
    }


    vec4 finalPosition = mix(position, skinnedVertexPosition, skinningEnabled);
    vec4 finalNormal = mix(vec4(normal, 0.), skinnedNormal, skinningEnabled);

    vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * finalNormal.xyz);
    vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0., 0., 2.);
    lIntensity = max(0.0, dot(eyeNormal, normalize(lightPosition)));



    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelMatrix * finalPosition;
}
```

The result is that the animation displays wrong in terms of orientation. That is, instead of bobbing up and down it bobs in and out (along what I think is the Z axis according to my transform in the export clip). And the rotation angle is counterclockwise instead of clockwise.

If I try with a more than one joint, then it's almost as if the second joint rotates in it's own different coordinate space and does not follow 100% its parent's transform. Which I assume it should from my animation subsystem which I assume in turn follows the theory I explained for the case of more than one joint.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you need to swap matrix multiplication arguments. Because normally you *first* transform from object space to local space, and *after that* you transform from local space to parent space. I.e. it should be `localBoneTransform * boneParentTransform`, Your code seems to do opposite. Also, before trying to use skeletal animation, first test your animation system on non-skeletal animated objects and make sure it actually works properly. Another thing is that you shouldn't calculate inverse bone transform every frame. Normally you calculate those matrices just once.

Comment: About testing the system on non-skeletal meshes.. well this is the skeletal animation section. I can't test it on non joint-driven vertices. I have another section (not shown here) which does rigid hierarchical animation, where an "object" is made up of multiple meshes and these are held in place and/or animated by doing a depth first search and concatenating the matrices of each mesh. And that works fine. About your observation on the transform order, can you tell me where in the code do you see that for example? trying to follow you.. thanks!

Comment: Oh and 2 things: I didn't put in the question (maybe I should) but I know I'm recalculating things and overall, not doing things the efficient way. This is is just my testing things out.. once I get everything right I go through all the codebase and even realign structs. For instance, it also doesn't make sense really to export the bind poses as TQS if then I'm not going to interpolate these but just convert them back into a matrix (unlike the keyframe poses which I do need to interpolate). And about testing the code with non-skeletal objects, I wonder if you mean in bind pose? If so, it works

Comment: " I can't test it on non joint-driven vertices" Of course you can. Instead of skinned mesh, draw a dummy box or something like that for every bone and see if it moves correctly in world space **while being animated**. Also, aside from "multiply by inverse bone transform" and actual mesh calculation, hierarchical skinned animation system should be completely identical to hierarchical "non-skinned" animation system. There's no reason for separate animation system just for skinned meshes.

Comment: "can you tell me where in the code do you see that for example?" `GLKMatrix4Multiply(currentPosePalette[aSkeleton.joints[i].parentIndex], currentTransform)`. I haven't worked with IOS(?) but normally in matrix multiplication routines local transform is first argument and parent transfomr is second argument. Another thing is that I don't see "inverse bone transform" actually being inverted - it is very likely that you'll have to calculate inverse matrix properly, because blender supports scaling.

Comment: I see what you mean about basically "Drawing the joints." About no need for a separate system, I'm with you in the general case, if this was "an engine." But it is not. The other section is different, driven by a CF-grammar through YACC and does other stuff.. Like I said, at this stage these are a bunch of tests for different things

Comment: Oh I just saw your pointing out the matrix multiplication. This is arbitrary. It depends on whether you are operating on column-major or row-major. GLK follows the OpenGL default convention of column major, so multiplication is right to left and vectors are column vectors. So the snippet you quoted reads" multiply the current transform by its parent's current transform." That is a vector multiplied by these would first be transformed by currentTransform and then by the parent transform. And the inverse calculation is in the export script, look under "For joint bind poses:"

Comment: Anyway, for skinned meshes testing normally goes like this: 1. Test if joints are animated properly. 2. Test if inverted transforms are correct. To do this, transform mesh using inverse transforms only (without bone transform). If everything is allright, you should get pile of "limbs" around point (0, 0, 0). 3. Add bone transforms see if mesh doesn't explode or deform.

Comment: "GLK follows the OpenGL default convention of column major" 1. AFAIK/FYI, opengl matrix layout is completely identical to directx matrix layout. See [OpenGL faq on transformations](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/transformations.htm).

Comment: no idea about direct X. All I can tell you is in column major, which is OpenGL's ordering by default (you can change it though) and was the norm too back when I took linear algebra in college, you multiply right to left since your vectors are column vectors.

Comment: Cross posted on gamedev: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/44058/9837

Comment: @casperOne You are right that it was cross posted.. sorry. However, why did you close it under off topic?? was it a mistake? I mean, it's a thorough question, shows I did my homework, shows the theory, the implementation... what else would you expect of an "on topic" question?

Comment: And what's with the downvote???? Again... am I getting punished for asking a question?